# Expected an identifier

Tags: c++

I was trying to find the absolute sum of an array.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int getAbsSum(vector<int> arr) {
    int result = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++)
    {
        result += abs(arr[i]);
    }

    return result;
}

int main() {
    cout << getAbsSum([3, 2, -3, -4]);
    return 0;
}
```

but I got this error that says "Expected an identifier" in my main function. I tried adding a typename before the array, like this

```
 cout << getAbsSum(int [3, 2, -3, -4]);
```

but it did not work.

Comment: this is not a c++ syntax. try `getAbsSum({3, 2, -3, -4});`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The meaning of `[ ]` is not what you convey in your example. [ ] is used to indicate array indices, and it only supports one argument. Hence, the expression `3, 2, -3, -4` in this context means evaluate 3, then evaluate 2, then -3, then -4 and return the result of evaluating -4. See

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other

Because the expressions `3`, `2` and `-3` have no side effects, the result here is the same as if you just wrote `-4`.
With respect to expecting an identifier error, the `operator [ ]` requires a variable in front of it, so `arr[1]` means return the second object in array (or container) arr.
The solution is to use the correct syntax for list-initialization, which is a form of uniform initialization (do not confuse with aggregate initialization, which is for aggregates. Vectors are not aggregates):

```
cout << getAbsSum({3, 2, -3, -4});
```

Also, I recommend not using `using namespace std;` in the global workspace, but only inside scopes, i.e. in functions, where the effect is limited in scope.
A modern version of this function can be rewritten as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>

template <typename E = int,
    template <typename> typename T = std::vector>
E getAbsSum(T<E> const& arr){ 
    E result {};
    for (E element : arr)
    {
        result += abs(element);
    }
    return result;
}

int main() {
    using namespace std;
    using namespace std::literals;
    cout << getAbsSum({3, 2, -3, -4}) << '\n';
    cout << getAbsSum(vector<double>{2.3, 4.5, 6}) << '\n';
    cout << getAbsSum(vector<chrono::seconds>{10s, 1min}).count() << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

This version supports any arithmetic type and any container.

In response to @foodiecookies:

(1) Here, the line `E result {};` means that the default constructor for E is called. If we used `E result = 0` then there would be an error on initialization of `chrono::seconds`, but if we used `E result`, the arithmetic types would not get initialized, which is undefined behavior. `E result {}` calls the default constructor on complex types and a value of 0 or equivalent (0.f, 0., false, ...) for basic types.

(2) `for (auto var : container)` is a range-based loop. See
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for
It is considered safer and easier to read. Use the old `for(;;)` when you are not iterating over all the elements in the container.

(bonus) `abs(element)` finds the correct version of the `abs` function thanks to Argument Dependent Lookup
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl

Comment: Hi, may I ask you 2 questions about the code that you have rewritten? 1. ` E result {}; `  What does the brackets {} mean? And why do we need it for variable initialization?  2. ` for (E element : arr) ` I have seen quite a few people putting colon rather than semi-colon inside a for loop. Would you mind explaining what this line of code does?  Thank you!

Comment: @foodiecookies I have edited the answer to include a use case with time durations and reply to your questions in the last paragraph..

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

`[]` brackets aren't used in C++ like that. You seem to want to use [List Initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization), which uses the `{}` instead:

```
cout << getAbsSum({3, 2, -3, -4});
```

Also, I'm pretty sure the type name keyword is counter-productive here. It's at the very least redundant in this context.

Answer (score 1):

Like this

```
cout << getAbsSum({3, 2, -3, -4});
```

This syntax is called *uniform initialization* and was introduced in C++11.